# How can I solve "world writable" issues with modules uploaded to PAUSE (CPAN) from Win32?

Tags: perl, cpan

Does anyone one know how not to get the "world writables" fail message from PAUSE when I upload a module to PAUSE?

I packed it with `make dist` on Windows. I haven't got access to a Linux box at work and I need to work it out on Windows.

Comment: From rindolf on irc: you can add TAR_FLAGS

Comment: rindolf(Shlomi Fish)'s answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307368//1307622#1307622

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a script on PerlMonks that fixes things up. The URL is http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=731935

Answer (score 4):

As noted in [GNU Tar manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/man1/tar.1.html) , you can use the TAR_OPTIONS environment variable to pass arguments to the tar command. One of them is --mode= . Read the man page for more information.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Module::Build for your dist building, you can install the latest version, accompanied with Archive::Tar and it will be fixed for you. No mess, no fuss.